# Delete function first or last record

Tags: vb.net, jet

My main menu is where all records are displayed. The user can navigate between records by a list table which has all the records.
When i use the this code to delete a displayed record, allways the first record gets deleted.

```
BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs")
    .RemoveAt(BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs").Position)
```

Ive added an extra line in which the position should match the ID of the record.

```
BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs").Position = Job_IDTextBox
BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs")
    .RemoveAt(BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs").Position)
```

NOTE: Job_IDTextBox is directly connected to the column in the database (I dragged it from the datasource menu into the form in details form)

My goal is so that i can delete the job that has been selected (and displayed) from the list box (with all records in it)

Comment: Your tags are misleading.  VB6 and VBA are different.  Are you working in MS Access or Visual Basic?

Comment: Im sorry i dont really know the difference, Im working in Visual Basic and my program is connected to the database in access.

Comment: If you are working with Visual Studio then you are using `vb.net` as programming language. The database you are using doesn't have to do anything with the programming language. If you are using an Access mdb then the database engine is `JET`.

Comment: A `TextBox` is not an `Integer` number. `Job_IDTextBox.Text` is a string and you have to convert it into an `Integer` with `Convert.ToInt32(Job_IDTextBox.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

Right so ive changed my code to

```
BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs").Position = Convert.ToInt32(Job_IDTextBox.Text)
    BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs").RemoveAt(BindingContext(JobsDBDataSet, "T_Jobs").Position)
```

And the same thing still happens: last job is deleted and not the selected one (from the listbox). I have a feeling its a problem regard the listbox, and maybe I'd firstly have to tell the program to change its pointer to the job ive chosen from the list box but i have no idea how to do this - and this is just an assumption.